# "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, cardlayout, jmenu

first of all, I apologize for my English, much of this text I have made with the translator of google.
As for the problem, try using CardLayout by JMenu and attempting to show the different views, I jump the error.
I was googling and looking at the same page, I found similar things, but to apply the problem persists.
Below is the code for what I've done:

```
public class Principal extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
//variables menu
private final CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
private final JPanel panelSuperior = new JPanel(), panelInferior = new JPanel(), panelPrincipal = new JPanel(),
        panelVentas = new JPanel();
private final JMenuBar barMenu = new JMenuBar();
private final JMenu menuPrincipal = new JMenu(), menuProductos = new JMenu();
private final JMenuItem menuVenta = new JMenuItem(), menuProdAgregar = new JMenuItem(), menuProdBuscar = new JMenuItem(),
        menuProdActualizar = new JMenuItem(), menuFaltante = new JMenuItem(), menuSalir = new JMenuItem();
//variables de ventanas
private JLabel tituloVentana;

public Principal(){
    initWinPanelSuperior();
    initWinPrincipal();
    initWinPanelVenta();
    initWinPanelInferior();
    initWindow();
}

private void initWinPanelSuperior(){        
    setJMenuBar(barMenu);
    menuPrincipal.setText("Menu");

    menuVenta.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F1, 0));
        menuVenta.setText("Ventas");
        menuVenta.addActionListener(this);
        menuPrincipal.add(menuVenta);

    menuProductos.setText("Productos");

    menuProdAgregar.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0));
        menuProdAgregar.setText("Agregar");
        menuProdAgregar.addActionListener(this);
        menuProductos.add(menuProdAgregar);

    menuProdActualizar.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F3, 0));
        menuProdActualizar.setText("Actualizar");
        menuProdActualizar.addActionListener(this);
        menuProductos.add(menuProdActualizar);

    menuProdBuscar.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F5, 0));
        menuProdBuscar.setText("Buscar");
        menuProdBuscar.addActionListener(this);
        menuProductos.add(menuProdBuscar);

    menuPrincipal.add(menuProductos);

    menuFaltante.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F6, 0));
        menuFaltante.setText("Mostrar faltante");
        menuFaltante.addActionListener(this);
        menuPrincipal.add(menuFaltante);

    menuSalir.setAccelerator(javax.swing.KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F4, 0));
        menuSalir.setText("Salir");
        menuSalir.addActionListener(this);
        menuPrincipal.add(menuSalir);

    barMenu.add(menuPrincipal);
    barMenu.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

}
private void initWinPrincipal(){
    JLabel titulo = new JLabel();
        titulo.setText("Bienvenidos");
        titulo.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 200);
        titulo.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", 0, 42));
        titulo.setVisible(true);

     panelPrincipal.add(titulo);

}
private void initWinPanelVenta(){
    tituloVentana = new JLabel();
        tituloVentana.setBounds(200, 0, 180, 30);
        tituloVentana.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 38));
        tituloVentana.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        tituloVentana.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        tituloVentana.setText("Ventas");
        tituloVentana.setVisible(true);

    panelVentas.add(tituloVentana);
}

private void initWinPanelInferior(){

    panelInferior.setLayout(cardLayout);
        panelInferior.add(panelPrincipal, "principal");
        panelInferior.add(panelVentas, "ventas");

}


private void initWindow(){
    JPanel panel = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        this.add(panelSuperior);
        this.add(panelInferior);
        this.pack();
        this.getPreferredSize();
        this.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setTitle("Sys");
        this.show();
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getSource() == menuVenta) {
        //problem here
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) panelInferior.getLayout();
        cl.show(panelVentas, "ventas");
    }
    if (e.getSource() == menuSalir) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Here the trace of the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong parent for CardLayout
at java.awt.CardLayout.checkLayout(CardLayout.java:404)
at java.awt.CardLayout.show(CardLayout.java:526)
at Vista.Principal.actionPerformed(Principal.java:121)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: when I run the program, just click on "Ventas" skips the error and does not show the JLabel with the text "Ventas"

Comment: Ty men, I spent two days looking as was the solution, and it was something as simple

Comment: You're welcome ! :) Have a nice time working on that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`CardLayout#show(Container, String)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html#show(java.awt.Container,%20java.lang.String)) takes as first argument the actual container of the layout object. The second argument is the name you've given to the card-component, in this case it is `ventas` as you may see below.

```
panelInferior.add(panelVentas, "ventas");
```

So :

- First argument : container on which the `layout` has been added.
- Second argument : name of the `Card` component.

---

### Solution

```
cl.show(panelVentas, "ventas");
```

should actually be

```
cl.show(panelInferior, "ventas");
```